# Equation of a bounded plane in 3D

Tags: geometry, plane-geometry

By bounded I mean the plane does not extend to infinity in either direction $x,y,z$. For example, can we determine the equation of a rectangular plane orthogonal to the z-axis, i.e., cutting the z-axis at $z=3$ while its x-side and y-side are equal to $d$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:
$$\left(\left| u\right| -\left| v\right| ,\left| u\right| +\left| v\right| ,3\right),u\in[-3,3],v\in[-3,3]$$

Hope it is useful

$$...$$

[image]